# How to analyze this FIFO program?

Tags: c, buffer, pool, fifo

Here are some pieces of the program that completes FIFO buffer pool. I don't know how does it complete. Does anyone help me to analyze it?

This is a struct of `FlameHandle`, this struct stores total flames, the first frame, and the last frame.

```
typedef struct FlameHandle{
    PageFlame *first;
    PageFlame *last;
    PageFlame *totalFlames;
    int numWriteIO;
    int numReadIO;
} FlameHandle;
```

This is a struct of `PageFlame`, this struct stores info of each flame.

```
typedef struct PageFlame{
    char *data;
    PageNumber pageNum;
    bool isDirty;
    int fixCount;
    struct PageFlame *next;
    struct PageFlame *prev;
} PageFlame;
```

This is a struct of `BM_BufferPool`

```
typedef struct BM_BufferPool {
    char *pageFile;
    int numPages;   
    ReplacementStrategy strategy;
    void *mgmtData; // use this one to store the bookkeeping info your buffer
    // manager needs for a buffer pool
} BM_BufferPool;
```

This is a struct of `BM_PageHandle`

```
typedef struct BM_PageHandle {
    PageNumber pageNum;
    char *data;
} BM_PageHandle;
```

This is a function `pinPage`.

```
RC pinPage(BM_BufferPool *const bm, BM_PageHandle *const page, const PageNumber pageNum)
{
    FlameHandle *FH;
    FH = bm->mgmtData;
    page->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*PAGE_SIZE);
    SM_FileHandle fh;
    PageFlame *pf;
    openPageFile(bm->pageFile,&fh);
    page->pageNum = pageNum;
    for(int i=0; i<bm->numPages;i++)
    {
        pf = &(FH->totalFlames)[i];
        if((FH->totalFlames[i]).pageNum == NO_PAGE)
        {
            FH->totalFlames[i].pageNum = pageNum;
            pf->fixCount++;
            ensureCapacity(pageNum+1,&fh);

            //Reads new flame from fh and stores it to (FH->first)->data).
            readBlock(pageNum,&fh,(FH->first)->data); 
            FH->numReadIO++;
            strcpy(page->data,(FH->first)->data);
            FH->last = FH->first;
            if(FH->last->next == NULL)
            {
                FH->first = FH->totalFlames;
            }
            else
            {
                (FH->first) = (FH->last)->next;
            }
            return RC_OK;
        }
    }
}
```

In this function, It needs to store a new flame in an empty flame (`pageNum == NO_PAGE`), and at the same time, it needs to keep the FIFO sequence. I really cannot understand the semantics of following code:

```
if(FH->last->next == NULL){
    FH->first = FH->totalFlames;
}else
{
  (FH->first) = (FH->last)->next;
}
```

Does anyone can help me?
Here is the link of the whole project on GitHub:
https://github.com/randywhisper/assign_cs525/blob/master/assign2/buffer_mgr.c

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't understand the syntax or the semantics of the lines?

Comment: The semantics of the lines

Comment: Could u share the whole project on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the code you pasted there is `RS_FIFO`.

You can run the code using your pen.

In `initBufferPool` function, you create a `Doubly linked list` named `PageFlame`.
`PageFlame` have N `totalPageFlames`.

`PageFlame`'s fist points to `totalPageFlames[0]`, `last` points to end.

---

`FIFO` is first in first out.

Suppose you have a `PageFlame`(length 4) like `a,b,c,d`.

Here comes your snippet code.

`FH->last = FH->first`, `last->next` is `b`, not NULL, so goes to `(FH->first) = (FH->last)->next;`.
That means , `last` points to a while `first` points to b.

---

Next run, `last` points to b while `first` points to c.

a is read first and then `first` moves to next one `b`.

I think this is clear.

---

When there is only one element `d` and `d->next` is `NULL`.
So first will move from last out element `c` to `d`. When next element `e` comes in the queue, first will move to the `e` and last stay in `d`.

`RS_FIFO`, first in first out. That is it.

Comment: PageFlame has N totalPageFlames？ It does not mean that totalPageFlames has N PageFlame?

Comment: @Junrui  TotalPageFlames has N PageFlame.